# A better way of balancing a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, optimization, partitioning

I'm learning Haskell by solving some online problems and training exercises.

Right now I'm trying to write a function that'd take a list and balance it like this

```
[2,3,2,3,2] ---> [[2,2,2], [3,3]]
[1,2,3,7,8] ---> [[1,2,7], [3,8]]
[1,2,9,10] ---> [[2,9],[1,10]]
[1,1,1,1,1,2,3] ---> [[1,1,1,1,1],[2,3]]
```

(always in two parts, either works in the case of 2nd)

---

The way I thought of doing this was by using [Permutation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations) function from base Data.List

and filtering out valid lists with a function like this

```
sumCheck x
  | sum (take (length x `div` 2) x) == sum (drop (length x `div` 2) x) = True
  | otherwise = False
```

if the length of the list is even. If not then a recursive function that'd

```
(take y x) (drop (y - (y - 0)) x)
(take (y - 1) x) (drop (y - (y - 1)) x)
```

and so on.

or by just partitioning them like this

```
parts :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
parts [] = [([], [])]
parts (x : xs) = let pts = parts xs in
    [(x : ys, zs) | (ys, zs) <- pts] ++ [(ys, x : zs) | (ys, zs) <- pts]
```

then checking the balance by

```
checkBal (xs, ys) = abs (sum xs - sum ys)
```

and sorting in ascending order, where the first one would be most balanced.

---

Now this works well for smaller lists but as you might have guessed, for large lists, it just keeps on processing.

I think [binPack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Binpack-0.4.1/docs/Data-BinPack.html) could help with this but I rather not use external packages and try to do it on my own. (with some help ofc!)

Comment: This looks like a problem to solve with dynamic programming: create a list that stores the difference between the two partions, iterate over the elements, and each time update the list with the new balance.

Comment: Why not [1,3,4], [2,6] for second example?

Comment: @DavidFletcher That's actually correct, I came up with an example for unbalanced list from top of my head, forgot to double check it. Added better examples.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure dynamic programming helps much here. For example, the balancing of `[2,2,3,5,6]` is `([2,2,5],[3,6])`. This solution appears unrelated to the balancing of either `[2,3,5,6]` (namely, `([3,5], [2,6])`, which unlike the larger balancing puts the `2` and the `6` together) or `[2,2,3,5]` (namely, `([5], [2,2,3])` or `([5,2], [2,3])`, both of which separate one of the `2`'s from the `5`).

Comment: @DanielWagner: well it works in *O(n k)* with *k* the sum of the numbers and *n* the number of elements, and with some clever optimizations, *k* can be reduced. It is basically a bit equivalent to the *subset* sum problem, but the point is that here the *target sum* changes dynamically. The advantage of using dynamic programming over backtracking, is that we will not investigate two "partial" subsets that have the same sum.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah. In that case, I believe my answer implements pretty much what you have in mind... unfortunately *k* is still exponential in *n* in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a fun algorithm problem. I encourage you to keep thinking about it on your own; severe spoilers below.

Here's my plan: I'm going to compute all the possible sums of subsets, together with (just one) witness of who's in and who's out to achieve that sum. Then we'll just check which possible sum is closest to half the entire list's sum. So:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Sums a = Map a ([a], [a])

update :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Sums a -> Sums a
update n sums = M.union
    (                          (\(i, o) -> (i, n:o)) <$> sums)
    (M.mapKeysMonotonic (n+) $ (\(i, o) -> (n:i, o)) <$> sums)

computeSums :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Sums a
computeSums = foldr update (M.singleton 0 ([], []))

balance :: (Integral a, Ord a) => [a] -> ([a], [a])
balance xs = snd . fromJust $ M.lookupLE (sum xs `div` 2) (computeSums xs)
```

Trying it out:

```
> mapM_ (\xs -> putStrLn $ show xs ++ " ---> " ++ show (balance xs)) [[2,3,2,3,2],[1,2,3,7,8],[1,2,9,10],[1,1,1,1,1,2,3]]
[2,3,2,3,2] ---> ([3,3],[2,2,2])
[1,2,3,7,8] ---> ([3,7],[1,2,8])
[1,2,9,10] ---> ([2,9],[1,10])
[1,1,1,1,1,2,3] ---> ([2,3],[1,1,1,1,1])
```

It also terminates relatively quickly on large lists:

```
> :set +s
> (\(a,b) -> (sum a, sum b)) . balance $ replicate 1001 1
(500,501)
(0.12 secs, 156,255,000 bytes)
> (\(a,b) -> (sum a, sum b)) . balance $ [1..200]
(10050,10050)
(1.25 secs, 752,015,256 bytes)
> (\(a,b) -> (sum a, sum b)) . balance $ take 20 (iterate (2*) 1)
(524287,524288)
(0.92 secs, 532,754,784 bytes)
```

This last example exercises the exponential worst-case behavior of this algorithm (since every subset of the powers of two gives a different sum).